# Writing a buffer to a struct seems to not be working

Tags: c++, struct

I am working on a project that is aiming to create a simple version of a file system for a class. I am running into trouble when I work with the "inode" structure that we have defined. The inode structure is defined as follows:

```
struct iNode
 {
  char name[8]; //file name
  int size;     // file size 
  int blockPointers[8]; // direct block pointers
  int used;             // 0 if free; 1 if in use
};
```

I also have the following code later on in my project:

```
char* inodes = NULL;
inodes = new char[48];
iNode *myinode = new iNode();
int inodemax = 16;
int storedi = 0;
int x = 0;
while(x < inodemax){
  disk.seekg(128 + 48*x,ios::beg);
  disk.read(inodes, 48);
  inodex = (struct iNode *)  &inodes;
  if(inodex -> used == 0){
    inodex -> used = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
      inodex -> name[i] = name[i];
    }
    inodex -> size = size;
    storedi = disk.tellg();
    break;
  }
  if(inodex -> used != 0 && x == 15){
    return 4;
  }
  x = x +1;
}
```

I am not well versed in c++ so any obvious errors may come at the expense of my limited knowledge in the language (I am better experienced with C). My problem comes with the fact that the I create a test case where the inodes used field should be 0- yet the return statement of "4" is returned. It shouldn't reach that part of the code.

When I manually change my code to just get the "used" field from the inodes buffer then it works correctly. So I am led to believe that I am doing something wrong with copying my char* buffer into my struct.

Can anyone pinpoint what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it? I have been stuck on this for a while, thanks.

Comment: Please give a [MCVE]. Without that we don't have the full context and can't be reasonably  expected to debug the issue.

Comment: You shouldn't be using that magic value of `48`; use `sizeof(iNode)` instead.

Comment: @kaylum This is the only part of my project I am currently facing difficulty of. What "context" is missing?

Comment: Furthermore, have you opened the file in binary, not text mode? What does stepping through the routine in a debugger tell you about what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inodes = new char[48];
```

`inodes` is a pointer to a buffer of 48 bytes.

```
inodex = (struct iNode *)  &inodes;
```

This sets `inodex` to point to the `inodes` pointer. Not what `inodes` is pointing to, but to the pointer itself.

It's fairly obvious that this should really be:

```
inodex = (struct iNode *)  inodes;
```

or, to be more explicit:

```
inodex = reinterpret_cast<struct iNode *>(inodes);
```

Comment: Of course, casting an arbitrary byte array to a `struct` is a minefield that will go horribly wrong if any inheritance, etc, comes into play!

Comment: The line of code you fixed actually came straight from my instructor that I copied and pasted (I was worried that a line I added myself was wrong). 


Thanks for your help.